# ** (Mix) Could not start application rumbl: Rumbl.start(:normal, [])

Tags: phoenix-framework

If you have the next error in your terminal:

```
 (Mix) Could not start application rumbl: Rumbl.start(:normal, []) returned an error: shutdown: failed to start child: Rumbl.Repo
     (EXIT) an exception was raised:
         (UndefinedFunctionError) undefined function Rumbl.Repo.start_link/0
            (rumbl) Rumbl.Repo.start_link()
            (stdlib) supervisor.erl:358: :supervisor.do_start_child/2
            (stdlib) supervisor.erl:341: :supervisor.start_children/3
            (stdlib) supervisor.erl:307: :supervisor.init_children/2
            (stdlib) gen_server.erl:328: :gen_server.init_it/6
            (stdlib) proc_lib.erl:240: :proc_lib.init_p_do_apply/3
```

Answer (score 4):

Just add this before last end, in your repo.ex file:

```html
 def start_link do
    {:ok, self}
 end
```

Answer (score 3):

In `lib/rumbl.ex`, comment out the line that starts the repository:

```
# Start the Ecto repository
# supervisor(Rumbl.Repo, []),
```